# Unescaping HTML entities with XSLT

Tags: xslt, escaping, entity

I have external script result in my XSL template, contains escaped html special characters. How I can unescape it with XSLT and output it to final document?

I have already escaped result, `disable-output-escaping="yes"` can't help me.

For example (result from external script):

```
&lt;!--376473658726587--&gt;
&lt;a href="/"&gt;some text&lt;/a&gt;
```

Comment: Please show what you have, I can probably help you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="script">
  &lt;script>
    <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()"/>
  &lt;/script>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document** (you failed to provide one !!!):

```
<script>
&lt;!--376473658726587--&gt;
&lt;a href="/"&gt;some text&lt;/a&gt;
</script>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
  <script>
    <!--376473658726587--> <a href="/">some text</a>
  </script>
```

Comment: @VeroLom: So, you need 2-step XSLT processing, or you need to write an extension function to be called from your XSLT code, that does the unescaping. There are no standard unescaping functions until XPath 3.0 / XSLT 3.0, but these are still working drafts only.